# How to store ids for a rating system?

Tags: php, mysql, store, rating

all

I need a quick help on how to store the ids of the rater in mysql database to use it in php script. like
I have a php star rating script and i want that when someone rates a profile his/her id should be stored in database to check if they already voted. How can I store it in a single column with other raters profile id. The database structure is like this

```
    user_id | rated_value | rated_count | raters_id
```

Here user_id is the id of the profile which is being rated
rated_value is the total value of all votes
rated_count is the number of total rates ever rated to the specific profile.
and raters_id is the id of all raters who rated that profile.

now i want to check if the profile id already rated a profile with php. I have heard of comma separated list of ids but is it a good idea. And how can i check in php if the id is already rated a profile if i use a comma separated list.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You need only 3 columns:

```
user_id | rated_value | rater_id
```

And you will have to store every single rating here, so you can even inform user how many stars he rated in the past.

To get total rating for `user_id = 1` use aggregating functions and grouping in MySQL:

```
SELECT 
    AVG(rated_value) as average_rating, 
    COUNT(*) AS number_of_votes 
FROM 
    user_rating 
WHERE
    user_id = 1
GROUP BY
    user_id
```

To check if `rater_id = 3` rated `user_id = 1` use simple query

```
SELECT rated_value FROM user_rating WHERE user_id = 1 AND rater_id = 3
```

And check if it return any results

Comment: but still how i can store the rater_id in database because there will many ids that will rate a profile

Comment: In my solution every row in `user_rating` is for every vote so if two users will rate `user_id=1` there will be two rows with `user_id=1` anb both of them will have different `rater_id`.

Comment: okay, but can you give an idea about having a different table for just storing the rater_id. is it possible?

Comment: Yes it is possible and you should be able to figure it out from my answer.